# I'm having trouble finding a request test for play in scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, tdd

I Have Play 2.2 in Scala and am somewhat new to the framework. I can't seem to figure out how to do request tests, I can figure out integration tests, but not request tests. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be extremely helpful.

I looked at this, but I don't want to test the controller, the model, or do an integration test. I just want to post to the route and verify that it returns what I expect.
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTest

Comment: [play scala Routing](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaRouting)

Comment: Thank you, I would like to write automated tests to verify data is returned as expected from a specific endpoint actually. I have my routes set up properly and the app is acting as expected excluding it not having tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFunctionalTest:

```
"respond to the index Action" in new WithApplication() {
  val Some(result) = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/Bob"))

  status(result) must equalTo(OK)
  contentType(result) must beSome("text/html")
  charset(result) must beSome("utf-8")
  contentAsString(result) must contain("Hello Bob")
}
```

Comment: not found: value fakeApplication
I'm assuming there's something I'm missing
WithApplication(fakeApplication)

Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: I'm getting an error with "fakeApplication" where do I get that from?
I looked in the documentation, I guess I'm a little confused because I'm coming from rails, and you can just test the application, you don't have to tell it what application you are testing.

Comment: Edited to remove the fakeApplication parameter, it's not needed if you haven't created a custom fake application.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I figured it out. I'm not sure if its the best way, but it fit what I was trying to do.

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import org.junit.runner._

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.libs.json._

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])                                                                                                                   
class UsersSpec extends Specification {

"Users" should {

    "render index request" in new WithApplication{

        val response = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/users")).get

        val result = Map("next" -> "hello")
        contentAsString(response) must contain (Json.toJson(result).toString)
        contentType(response) must beSome.which(_ == "application/json")
    }
}
```